# Latest records/messages present in a topic kafka

Tags: apache-kafka

Is there a way to fetch the latest 1000 records/messages present in a topic in kafka ? similar to `tail -f 1000` in case of a file in linux ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using Python Kafka I think!!! I found this way to get the last message.

Configure it to get n last messages but make sure there are enough messages in case the topic is empty. this looks like a job for streaming i.e Kafka streams or Kafka SQL

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from kafka import KafkaConsumer, TopicPartition

TOPIC = 'example_topic'
GROUP = 'demo'
BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS = ['bootstrap.kafka:9092']

consumer = KafkaConsumer(
    bootstrap_servers=BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS,
    group_id=GROUP,
    # enable_auto_commit=False,
    auto_commit_interval_ms=0,
    max_poll_records=1
)

candidates = []
consumer.commit()

msg = None
partitions = consumer.partitions_for_topic(TOPIC)

for p in partitions:
    tp = TopicPartition(TOPIC, p)
    consumer.assign([tp])
    committed = consumer.committed(tp)
    consumer.seek_to_end(tp)
    last_offset = consumer.position(tp)
    print(f"\ntopic: {TOPIC} partition: {p} committed: {committed} last: {last_offset} lag: {(last_offset - committed)}")

    consumer.poll(
        timeout_ms=100,
        # max_records=1
    )

    # consumer.assign([partition])
    consumer.seek(tp, last_offset-4)

    for message in consumer:
        # print(f"Message is of type: {type(message)}")
        print(message)
        # print(f'message.offset: {message.offset}')

        # TODO find out why the number is -1
        if message.offset == last_offset-1:
            candidates.append(message)
            # print(f'  {message}')

            # comment if you don't want the messages committed
            consumer.commit()
            break

print('\n\ngooch\n\n')

latest_msg = candidates[0]

for msg in candidates:
    print(f'finalists:\n {msg}')
    if msg.timestamp > latest_msg.timestamp:
        latest_msg = msg

consumer.close()


print(f'\n\nlatest_message:\n{latest_msg}')
```

I know that in Java/Scala Kafka Streams there is a possibility to create a table i.e a sub topic with only the last entry in another topic so confluence Kafka library in c might offer a more elegant and efficient way. it has python and java bindings and kafkacat CLI.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `seek` method of `KafkaConsumer` class - you need to find current offsets for every partition, and then perform calculation to find correct offsets.

Answer (score 0):

```
consumer = KafkaConsumer()
partition = TopicPartition('foo', 0)
start = 1234
end = 2345
consumer.assign([partition])
consumer.seek(partition, start)
for msg in consumer:
    if msg.offset > end:
        break
    else:
        print msg
```

[source](https://github.com/dpkp/kafka-python/issues/648)